# How to turn off or fix: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.ts(2339) on Typescipt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code and although it works like a charm, TS complains that "children" does not exist. I tried turning it off but that didn't have an effect. How can I solve this error either by turning it off or adding the correct type?

> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.ts(2339)

```
 const pElement = React.useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null)

  if (id % 2 === 0) {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line  */ 
 pElement.current!.parentElement!.nextSibling!.children[3].classList.remove(class)
      } else {
   /* eslint-disable-next-line  */ 
pElement.current!.parentElement!.previousSibling!.children[3].classList.remove(class)
          }
```

Comment: You could potentially do an unsafe cast of `nextSibling` to an HTMLElement.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Cast/assert with `as` => `(pElement.current!.parentElement!.nextSibling as HTMLElement).children`